# camera kinect/video

Tags: kinect, opencv, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, that I have done, now I want to save the images I have listened to from to video using the video writer class,
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
However,  I don't want to use the default camera (webcam), instead the kinect camera. I have tried -1, but still won't work.
So, If someone has opened a capture using KINECT camera, that would be great if they shared with me how they did it.
many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10735/camera-kinect/video/) by [robwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/751/robwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-26**:
Duplicate http://answers.ros.org/question/1697/capture-for-kinect-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate http://answers.ros.org/question/1697/capture-for-kinect-camera - tfoote (Jul 26)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0